# CSS: is it possible to scale the image in a :before {content:url(..)} element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

ok, I admit I'm in the realm of playing around now...

What I want to achieve:
there should be a plus sign before utility links that are used to add some elements in our web application.
It would be good if this sign scales according to the font size the user has set.

What I've tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
   a.addLink:before {
      content: url('images/add.png'); height: 1.2em;    
   }
</style>

<a class="addLink" href="#" onclick="freakyJSFunction">testlink</a>
```

sadly, the height attribute is ignored.
I know i could just insert a normal `<img../>` before every link, but that's not as maintainable as we want it to be.

Or I can use one of the fancy unicode characters, for example

```
content: "\271a";  font-size:1.4em; color:green;
```

for now, I'll go with the unicode idea (just tested this in IE8...nope, IE 8 doesn't display that character ("greek cross")...:-( )...ok, I will go with the unicode idea if I find a suitable charakter that is displayed in IE8, FF and maybe chrome..

still, I wonder if my initial idea is somehow doable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In css3 you have a `background-size` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/jQgQv/7/

However background-image can't be applied trough `content:` so it won't work in your case using `:before` - only as a normal class.

Comment: very cool, thanks. Sadly some of our clients are very conservative, so we will be stuck with IE8 for some time, so we can't use css3. Still, good to know